# Neo4j: Match Merge throwing Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

Tags: neo4j

I was trying to run a query in Neo4j to make a relationship between a recipe and ingredients:

```
MATCH (spongeCake:Cake {name: "Sponge Cake"}),
(white:Flour {name: "white"}),
(egg:Ingredient {name: "egg"}),
(butter:Ingredient {name: "butter"}),
(milk:Ingredient {name: "milk"}),
(sugar:Ingredient {name: "sugar"}),
(brown:Flour {name: "brown"}),

MERGE (spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 4, unit: "medium"}]->(egg),
(spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 50, unit: "grams"}]->(brown),
(spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 255, unit: "grams"}]->(sugar),
(spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 25, unit: "grams"}]->(milk),
(spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 300, unit:  "grams"}]->(white),
(spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 45, unit: "grams"}]->(butter);
```

For some reason MERGE is giving me a lot of trouble and I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid input 'MERGE': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or "shortestPath" (line 9, column 1 (offset: 250))
"MERGE (spongeCake)-[r:CONTAINS {quantity: 4, unit: "medium"}]->(egg)"
 ^
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax of what you want to achieve.

1. There is a comma before Merge so it will not work.
2. Too many commas in match so it will create cartesian products
3. Many commas in MERGE and it will not work, so I removed it.

Learn the syntax well. Goodluck!

..

```
MATCH (spongeCake:Cake {name: "Sponge Cake"}) 
MATCH (white:Flour {name: "white"}) 
MATCH (egg:Ingredient {name: "egg"}),
MATCH (butter:Ingredient {name: "butter"}) 
MATCH (milk:Ingredient {name: "milk"}) 
MATCH (sugar:Ingredient {name: "sugar"}) 
MATCH (brown:Flour {name: "brown"}) 

MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 4, unit: "medium"}]->(egg)
MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 50, unit: "grams"}]->(brown)
MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 255, unit: "grams"}]->(sugar)
MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 25, unit: "grams"}]->(milk)
MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 300, unit:  "grams"}]->(white)
MERGE (spongeCake)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 45, unit: "grams"}]->(butter)
RETURN spongeCake
```